# MYSQL - Ordem das colunas e desempenho

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

Posso está fazendo uma pergunta boba, mas vamos lá.

A ordem das colunas no `MYSQL` interfere alguma coisa em termos de desempenho de alguma forma (seja nas escritas ou nas pesquisas)?

As chaves estrangeiras estarem no início ou no fim, os campos tipo `TEXT`, `BLOB` e outros de grande volume estarem no inicio ou no fim, tipos primitivos no inicio da tabela, enfim... até onde ordem das colunas na tabela interfere alguma coisa...

Obrigado

Comment: não ocorre interferência de desempenho na ordenação das tabelas, até porque se você tiver em mente algo grande volumosa como `bigdata` geralmente distribuído em nodos(clusters) que maximiza o processamento, o banco de dados é projetado para armazenar ler dados e tabelas independente do formato e ordem. sua pergunta sugere uma resposta muito longa, mais resumindo, não interfere.

Comment: Obrigado @HebertdeLima... Já foi ótimo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**giordanolima**, sua pergunta NÃO é boba.

A ordem das colunas pode ter sim **GRANDE** impacto na performance em alguns SGBD como `SQL Server`, `Oracle` e `MySQL`.

Este post pode servir de guia para futuras referências. Algumas convenções podem ser adotadas:

1. Primary key **primeiro**
2. Foreign key **segundo**
3. Colunas pesquisadas frequentemente **terceiro**
4. Colunas atualizadas frequentemente **quarto**
5. Colunas com "null" permitido" por **último**

Um exemplo de diferença na performance está na requisição de uma index. O sistema do banco de dados encontra a linha baseada em algumas condições da index e retorna o endereço da linha. Agora, digamos que você está procurando por `"Idade"` e isto está em sua tabela:

```
Id int,
Nome varchar(100),
Idade int
```

O sistema precisa achar onde `Idade` começa, porque `Nome` tem posição indefinida. Porém, se você mudar a ordem para:

```
Id int,
Idade int,
Nome varchar(100)
```

Agora o sistema sabe que `Idade` foi encontrado `4 bytes` após o começo da linha. Entao, a ordem pode ter um impacto considerável **sim**.

Comment: Obrigado @Felipe... Ótima contribuição....

Comment: giordanolima, imagina! Se achou a resposta ideal, por favor marque-a! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

não ocorre interferência de desempenho na ordenação das tabelas, até porque se você tiver em mente algo grande volumosa como `bigdata` geralmente distribuído em nodos(clusters) que maximiza o processamento, o banco de dados é projetado para armazenar ler dados e tabelas independente do formato e ordem. sua pergunta sugere uma resposta muito longa, mais resumindo, não interfere.

algumas coisas para mais informações.
[Desempenho Banco](http://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/db2/o-mito-do-melhor-desempenho-em-banco-de-dados/)
[Link 2](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFMQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unipac.br%2Fsite%2Fbb%2Ftcc%2Ftcc-15ee06c022b6b866f2815b76757c667f.pdf&ei=2-6SVcClDYKXgwSTq5T4BA&usg=AFQjCNG9lIYvtVrJNLY-8QjgSQCj9cWCIg&sig2=43OB1oNZg8Jp6omoOM8Hjg&bvm=bv.96783405,d.eXY)
[link 3](http://pt.slideshare.net/jonas82/alto-desempenho-com-banco-de-dados-mysql)

fiz um pequeno teste para verificar a influencia na ordem das tabelas criando e deletando e criando as tabelas de varias de 3 formas, inserindo, deletando e lendo informações, segue o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
podemos notar o seguinte:
 alguns formas de criar de criar a tabela levam milissegundos a mais ou a menos para serem criados, porem quando repetidos varia para mais e para menos esses milissegundos(fica evidente que a interferência **maior** provem do **HARDWARE** e não da lógica)
em seguida fiz inserções e leitura e dados de acordo com as ordem das tabelas que foram criados, e também é possível perceber a mesma diferencia novamente relacionada a desempenho de hardware, por ultimo (destacado em azul) esta o que realmente importa, o tempo que o banco leva para retornar os valores, nas três formas que tentei, a busca foi instantânea levado menos de milissegundos (obviamente que não foram 0.000 sec's, existi de fato um tempo, porem é irrelevante  e o MySQL retorna como 0). o que temos é um chamado **Costume** para fazer as coisas, mais na pratica, não é bem assim...